# PC won't start & hearing some weird noise from psu power socket

Tags: power, troubleshooting, desktop-computer, help

My pc won't start, no lights at all, as if it's not receiving any power.

And when I re-fitting the cable in my psu, I keep hearing [this](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtKeZT3HT5eshfVb6LJZvC_TTKJJAA)
in its socket

I forgot the model & brand of some of the parts of the PC, I will list what I know

MOBO: MSI B450 tomahawk Max
CPU: Ryzen 5 3600
GPU: MSI Gaming X rtx 2060 super
PSU: seasonic brand

Comment: Sounds like an intermittent electrical connection by the plug. Can you try another power cable?

Comment: An interesting discussion: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1390481-seasonic-seems-to-be-the-most-hated-psu-brand-here-then-there-are-nice-discounts-going-on/ As above. If not the cable then it's the PSU itself.

Comment: @harrymc I dont have spare cable, but I think I will test the psu first if it really the one causing the issue